# Matlab: replace values in one matrix with another matrix according to their referenced locations

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, geotiff

I have two geotiff images (saying "A" and "B") imported in Matlab as matrices with `Geotiffread`. One has different values, while the second has only 0 and 255s.
What I'd like to do is replacing all the 255s with the values inside the other image (or matrix), according to their positions.
A and B differs in size, but they have the same projections.

I tried this:

```
A (A== 255)= B;
```

the output is the error:

```
??? In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.
```

Else, I also tried with the logical approach:

```
if A== 255
    A= B;
end
```

and nothing happens.

Is there a way to replace the values of A with values of B according to a specific value and the position in the referenced space?

Comment: Try `A(A==255) = B(A==255)`. The error is telling you that when you try to assign values to the elements of an array, you cannot give it any more or fewer values than you are trying to assign. Also, re the if statement: I believe that `if A==255` means the same as `if all(A==255)`, as in, if any elements of `A` are not `255`, false is returned. You can check this at the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to mask an image with a binary mask. You can do this:

```
BW = im2bw(B,0.5);
A=A.*BW;
```

hope it helps

Comment: I do not think this is masking at all. Also your solution will only work if A and B are the same size, which clearly from the question, they are not.

Comment: I could not use the im2bw function as You said because level argument only works with positive numbers from 0 to1, but I converted my 255s into 1s and the second line of Your code did the job. Thank You!

Comment: @umbe1987 you're right with the level, I edited my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

As darthbith put in his comment, you need to make sure that the number of entries you want to replace is the same as the number values you are putting in.

By doing `A(A==255)=B` you are trying to put the entire matrix B into the subset of A that equals 255.

However, if, as you said, the projections are the same, you can simply do `A(A==255) = B(A==255)`, under the assumption that B is larger or the same size as A.

Some sample code to provide a proof of concept.

```
A = randi([0,10],10,10);
B = randi([0,4],15,15);

C = A % copy original A matrix for comparison later
A(A==5) = B(A==5); % replace values
C==A % compare original and new
```

This example code creates two matrices, A is a 10x10 and B is a 15x15 and replaces all values that equal 5 in A with the corresponding values in B. This is shown to be true by doing `C==A` which shows where the new matrix and the old matrix vary, proving replacement did happen.

Answer (score 2):

Try `A(A==255) = B(A==255)`. The error is telling you that when you try to assign values to the elements of an array, you cannot give it any more or fewer values than you are trying to assign.

Also, regarding the if statement: `if A==255` means the same as `if all(A==255)`, as in, if any elements of `A` are not `255`, `false` is returned. You can check this at the command line.

If you're really desperate, you can use a pair of nested `for` loops to achieve this (assuming `A` and `B` are the same size and shape):

```
[a,b] = size(A);
for ii = 1:a
    for jj = 1:b
        if A(ii,jj) == 255
            A(ii,jj) = B(ii,jj);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I tried Your suggestion, but A is unchanged afterwards (all the 255s are not replaced with corresponding B values, and they still remain 255s).

Comment: your `if statement` statement is correct. It will run all on the vector used in the `if`

Comment: What type of data is in `A`? When I try at the command line: `A = [255 0 0 255]; B = [100 0 0 123]; A(A==255) = B(A==255)` I get `ans = [100 0 0 123]` which is exactly what I expect

Comment: A is 'single' type (it contains only 0s and 255s), while B is 'unit8'.

Comment: try casting A to a uint8, which should be okay since it is only between 0 and 255, and then try but this should not make a difference.

Comment: I tried the uint8 function on A, still getting the same results. Now I resized the matrices to be equals (numel now outputs the same result), but the problem is not solved.